# What is the quickest way to reach a mutual, symmetrical stalemate?

Tags: problems, stalemate, records

What is the fastest known game that ends that in a mutual stalemate position that is symmetrical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest known is in **37 plies.** I found this in Journal Entry #361 on [Tim Krabbe's website](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_19.htm), which in turn pulled it from the 2007 [5th issue](http://www.bestproblems.it/bppdf/BP044.pdf) of the chess magazine "Best Problems."

```
[Title "Evgeny Ghik, Shakhmatyi i Matematika 1983, Non-Unique Proof Game In 18.5 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 d5 2. e5 d4 3. c3 f6 4. Qf3 Kf7 5. Qxb7 Qd5 6. Kd1 Qxg2 7. Kc2 Qxf1 8. Qxc8 Qxg1 9. Qxb8 Rxb8 10. Rxg1 Rb3 11. Rg6 Ra3 12. Rh6 gxh6 13. bxa3 Kg7 14. Kb2 d3 15. e6 a5 16. h4 a4 17. h5 c5 18. f4 c4 19. f5
```

In case the PDF link goes cold, here are the relevant sections.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There was a previous stack exchange answer which has a very amusing position where neither side can make a legal move.

Take a look; it is very enjoyable!

[Mutual Stalemate](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/mutual-stalemate)

Answer (score 1):

To be straightforward, there is **no such thing as a mutual stalemate**. Saying

> neither side could move on their turn

is a bit confusing. If it's white's turn, then they can be stalemated. Black cannot be stalemated as well, because his opponent has not moved to put him in stalemate.

Comment: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/fun-with-chess/mutual-stalemate this is the first result from google