# What is the fastest possible stalemate by castling?

Tags: problems, castling, stalemate, records

It is [known](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28797/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-reach-stalemate) what the fastest stalemate is. But what but is the fastest possible stalemate in which castling must be the last move?

**33 plies** is my best result so far.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 h5 2. Qxh5 d6 3. Qxh8 Bh3 4. Qxg7 Bxg2 5. Qxg8 Bxf1 6. Qxf7+ Kd7 7. Qxf8 Kc6 8. Qxd8 e5 9. Qxd6+ Kb5 10. Qxc7 Bd3 11. Qxb8 Bxc2 12. Qxa8 Bd1 13. Qxa7 Kc4 14. Qxb7 Kd3 15. Nf3 Kc2 16. Qb3+ Kxc1 17. O-O
```

Castling for a pin isn’t the only possible motivation though. Here is **another 33 plies** sequence that shows motivation in protecting pieces and guarding squares.

```
[FEN ""]

1. f4 e5 2. fxe5 d6 3. exd6 Qg5 4. dxc7 Ke7 5. cxb8=Q Qxg2 6. Qxc8 Qxh2 7. Qxa8 Qxg1 8. Qxa7 g5 9. Qxb7+ Ke6 10. Qxf7+ Ke5 11. Qxf8 Qh2 12. Qxg8 Qh5 13. Qxh8+ Kf4 14. Qxh7 Kg4 15. Bg2 Kg3 16. Qxh5 g4 17. O-O
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve found a way to reduce the count down to **31 plies.**

```
[FEN ""]

1. f4 e5 2. fxe5 d6 3. exd6 Qg5 dxc7 Qxg2 5. cxb8=Q Qxh2 Qxa7 Qxg1 7. Qxa8 Qg2 8. Bxg2 g5 9. Qxb7 g4 10. Qxc8+ Ke7 11. Qxf8+ Ke6 12. Qxf7+ Ke5 13. Qxg8 Kf4 14. Qxh8 h5 15. Qxh5 Kg3 16. O-O
```

White has only two non-capturing moves, the first pawn move and casting. Black uses up all of their moves without rest. Therefore, I think that 31 plies may be optimal unless a pawn capture can be shaved off.

Answer (score 2):

27 piles

```
[FEN ""]

1. c4 a5 2. h4 h5 3. Qa4 Ra6 4. Qxa5 Rah6 5. Qxc7 f6 6. Qxd7+ Kf7 7. Qxb7 Qd3 8. Qxb8 Qh7 9. Qxc8 Kg6 10. g3 Kf7 11. Bg2 Kg6 12. Nh3 Kf7 13. Qe6+ Kg6 14. O-O 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: But this game (based on a well-known help stalemate in 19 plies) doesn't satisfy the condition because White had many stalemating moves other than 0-0.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I was just about to say as such, thank you. Notice the word 'must' in the question. Castling is not needed to induce the stalemate here.

Comment: I interpreted it as the last move played is castling.